# MYSQL query for selecting the result of a condition of one table and showing it on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

The 2nd row should be subtracted from 1st row...and display the result in 2nd table

1st table

```
--------------------------------
stock_name|temple|quantity|type
--------------------------------
rice      |shiva |  32    |purchase
rice      |shiva |  10    |issue
```

Initially 2nd table is empty

what exactly i need in 2nd table is as follows

```
---------------------------
stock_name|temple|quantity
--------------------------
rice      |siva  |22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Insert into Table2(stock_name,temple,quantity)
SELECT a.stock_name, a.temple, SUM(Case when Type='purchase' then quantity else (quantity*-1) End) AS quantity
FROM Table1 a
GROUP BY a.stock_name, a.temple
```

Comment: @naveen I used case when type =purchase than i add it value but when type is issue than i multiply it by -1 to make it negative and add it to current sum so it exctually subtract from it

Comment: sir..can u plz tell me the query for this plz
table1
--------------------------------
stock_name|temple|quantity|type
--------------------------------
rice      |shiva |  32    |purchase
rice      |shiva |  10    |issue
wheat     |ganesh|  50    | purchase
wheat     |ganesh|  45    | issue   
ghee      |ganesh|  50    | purchase
ghee      |ganesh|   5    | issue   

expected output in table2
--------------------------------
stock_name|temple|quantity|
--------------------------------
rice      |shiva |  22    |
wheat     |ganesh|  5     | 
ghee      |ganesh|  45    |

Comment: @naveen i m  leaving for home now...but i will slove query as soon as i come again i onlnie

Comment: @naveen the same query work for that too,,,seee here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27103/2

Comment: suppose if i inset stock_name=ghee,temple=shiva and quantity=23 for type purchase and quantity=12 for type = issue.....the result should overwrite the existing row in table2....can this is possible sir??

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO secondTable (stock_name,temple,quantity)
SELECT  stock_name,
        temple,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'purchase' 
                     THEN quantity 
                     ELSE quantity * -1 
                 END) quantity
FROM    firstTable
GROUP   BY stock_name, temple
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dee8/1)

What the query does is it inserts the result from the first table into the second table but with the calculated quantity already.

Comment: what's the problem? what else do you need?

Comment: can u explain me the query please?
   Thanx in advance

Comment: sir..can u plz tell me the query for this plz
table1
--------------------------------
stock_name|temple|quantity|type
--------------------------------
rice      |shiva |  32    |purchase
rice      |shiva |  10    |issue
wheat     |ganesh|  50    | purchase
wheat     |ganesh|  45    | issue   
ghee      |ganesh|  50    | purchase
ghee      |ganesh|   5    | issue   

expected output in table2
--------------------------------
stock_name|temple|quantity|
--------------------------------
rice      |shiva |  22    |
wheat     |ganesh|  5     | 
ghee      |ganesh|  45    |

Comment: please post the table structure along with your question so i can understand it.